# How to update multiple rows based on calculation on other table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a `Bets` table which user can bet any words. When a deadline is reached I announce results. I want to update user balance based on result I've announced.

`Accounts` :

| UserID | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.00$ |
| 2 | 2.0$. |

`Bets` :

| BetID | UserID | LuckWord | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hamburger | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | Book | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | Win | 2 |

`Results` :

| ID | Date | LuckyWord | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-20 | Book | 50 |

My PostgreSQL function to announce results and update balance :

```sql
Create or replace function public.announce_result(luckyWord text, price numeric)
returns void as
$$
begin
   -- Insert to result table
   insert into results(date, luckyWord) values (now(), $1);
   
   -- Update each user balance base on calculation
   select userId, sum(amount) as amount from bets where luckyWord != $1 group by userId;
   select userId, sum(amount) as amount from bets where luckyWord == $1 group by userId;

   -- How can I update each user balance base on result above?
   -- I could in programming language, but don't know how in SQL.

end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

After inserting and calculation I want account table to be:

| UserID | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 250.00$ |
| 2 | 0.0$ |

Comment: How did you arrive at $35, i.e., what math is performed when someone places a $5 bet on a LuckyWord with a $50 Price?

Comment: Ohh, I was wrong in provided example. But this is not really matter anyway, because in real system there will be more complex calculation than this, I just provide simple example. What matter is , How can I update that balance from that function after I do calculation

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of updating one table from another related table.

```
UPDATE accounts
SET accounts.balance = accounts.balance - bets.amount
FROM accounts, bets
WHERE accounts.userId = bets.userId AND bets.luckyWord=$1;
```